# Highcharts How to change align of data labels based on value

Tags: highcharts

I built a variwide chart with positive and negative values: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/051xwLgo/1/)

I want to change the align of the data labels of the poisitve values (blue) from right to left.

```
        series: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        negativeColor: 'rgb(179, 0, 18, .4)',
        threshold: 0,
        dataLabels: {
            allowOverlap: true,
            x: 0,
            align: 'right',
            enabled: true,
            verticalAlign : 'middle',
            formatter: function () {
               return this.point.name + ': ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.abs(this.point.y), 1);
           },
            style: {
                fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                fontWeight:'550',
                color:'#373737',
                fontSize: "14px",
                textOutline: false
        }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Hi @Johannes Christ, Your live example dosen't work. Could you fix it?

Comment: Hi, here is the update: https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/051xwLgo/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define data label alignment in the `complete` function:

```
  data: {
    ...,
    complete: function(data) {
      data.series[0].data.forEach(function(el) {
        el.dataLabels = {
          align: el.y > 0 ? 'left' : 'center'
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/aqn7p51x/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.complete